# ERROR: Catalina_Home Variable is not define correctly in this environment

Tags: tomcat, catalina

I just trying to running tomcat on my PC, but I got this error

> Catalina_Home Variable is not define correctly in this environment

FYI: I have tried to search about the error and find some information about this error. But, unfortunatelly, that doesn't solve my problem.

Here is the content of the startup.bat file. Thanks![enter image description here][1]

> @echo off rem Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more rem contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
>   distributed with rem this work for additional information regarding
>   copyright ownership. rem The ASF licenses this file to You under the
>   Apache License, Version 2.0 rem (the "License"); you may not use this
>   file except in compliance with rem the License.  You may obtain a copy
>   of the License at rem rem
>   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 rem rem Unless required by
>   applicable law or agreed to in writing, software rem distributed under
>   the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, rem WITHOUT WARRANTIES
>   OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. rem See the
>   License for the specific language governing permissions and rem
>   limitations under the License.
>
> if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" setlocal rem
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- rem Start script for the CATALINA Server rem rem $Id: startup.bat
>
> ### 895392 2010-01-03 14:02:31Z kkolinko $ rem
>
> rem Guess CATALINA_HOME if not defined set "CURRENT_DIR=%cd%" if not
>   "%CATALINA_HOME%" == "" goto gotHome set "CATALINA_HOME=%CURRENT_DIR%"
>   if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat" goto okHome cd .. set
>   "CATALINA_HOME=%cd%" cd "%CURRENT_DIR%" :gotHome if exist
>   "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat" goto okHome echo The CATALINA_HOME
>   environment variable is not defined correctly echo This environment
>   variable is needed to run this program goto end :okHome
>
> set "EXECUTABLE=%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat"
>
> rem Check that target executable exists if exist "%EXECUTABLE%" goto
>   okExec echo Cannot find "%EXECUTABLE%" echo This file is needed to run
>   this program goto end :okExec
>
> rem Get remaining unshifted command line arguments and save them in
>   the set CMD_LINE_ARGS= :setArgs if ""%1""=="""" goto doneSetArgs set
>   CMD_LINE_ARGS=%CMD_LINE_ARGS% %1 shift goto setArgs :doneSetArgs
>
> call "%EXECUTABLE%" start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
>
> :end

Comment: Did you start tomcat by `startup.bat`?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are running Tomcat via command line. 
Run Tomcat by navigating to the bin folder of the Tomcat installation.

Comment: I know this is 3 years old, but I would like to say thank you. If i could upvote this 1000x I would.